# Name of Part That Connects Blinds Wand With Blinds Roller and How to Replace It?

Tags: blinds

I have blinds where the part connecting the blinds roller and the blinds wand is broken.  The part looks like:

[image]

What's the name of this part?  How do I go about fixing / replacing it?

Comment: First idea was "tilt gear box", but I just made that up.  Not sure if that's the actual industry term for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a "wand tilt control".

http://www.fixmyblinds.com/vertical-blind-tilt-controls-s/91.htm